# How to access item by key in LWC html markup?

Tags: lightning-web-components

On layout, I need to show all the products and I need to mark products for which we have a price in pricebook. I created a Lightning Web Component to render one product and in the main component I'm rendering it by iterating through a list of products which I'm receiving from wired Apex method.

```
<template for:each={products} for:item="product">
    <lightning-layout-item key={product.Id} size="3" class="slds-p-around_x-small">
        <c-product-tile product={product}></c-product-tile>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</template>
```

I also have a list of prices, how can I pass this information to the component with a product? I wanted to get a specific price in the markup by product id but I don't think it is possible in LWC.

I need to pass information if there is a price for this product like this:

```
<template for:each={products} for:item="product">
    <lightning-layout-item key={product.Id} size="3" class="slds-p-around_x-small">
        <c-product-tile product={product} hasPrice={prices.contains(product.Id)}></c-product-tile>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</template>
```

I know that I can't pass it to `hasPrice` attribute like this but I need something similar. The only way can think of is to have two wired methods to receive products and prices and a separate method to combine them into one list which will be invoked from these two wired methods.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing? You seem to be passing the product accordingly, and assigning an id as a key.

Comment: I think you want to access the child in the for each you need to use queryselecterall you can set an attribute to identify the child uniquely

Comment: Hi, we will be able to help you better if you can show the code in JS also.

Comment: updated the description